# Generating the same random number for Game Center Match

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, game-center

I am in the process of creating an iOS multiplayer game and I want each player's screen to look EXACTLY like their opponents. For example, lets say I have 9 squares on the screen each with a number inside of them. I want each square on both screens to have exactly the same number. How can I do this through GameCenter? I understand how to send and receive data from player from player but I need a mechanism that sends the same number to both players in the game without each player generating their own random number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My best answer would be to pull the data from a source online etc.
Have one device as the designated 'randomness' maker, and have that device send that data to the other one to use. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a seeded random value.